# Generated .txt file doesn't show up

Tags: c#, bitmap, filestream, streamwriter

So, I'm tryng to generating a txt file with a matrix of 0 and 1, where all the borders are 0 and the body of the matrix is randomly filled with both values. It should be a bitMap where 0 is an obstacle and 1 is a possibile node for pathfinding algorythm. The Method should be called multiple times to generate and save in the folder as mush maps as the user want.

I made this class to generate the map:

```
public static class GenerateText
{
    static string obstacle = "0";
    static string node = "1";

    

    public static void CreateMap(int x, int y, string name)
    {
        string path = "Assets/" + name + ".txt";
        if(!File.Exists(name + ".txt"))
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);

            string[,] map = new string[x, y];
            for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
            {
                for (int h = 0; h < y; ++h)
                {
                    int randomValue = RandomGenerator.GetRandom(0, 10);
                    if (randomValue > 6 || i == 0 || h == 0 || i == x || h == y)
                    {
                        map[i, h] = obstacle;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        map[i, h] = node;
                    }
                }
            }
            fs.Close();
            writer.WriteLine(map);
        }
       
    }
}
```

and the result should be something like this:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

The called method works fine and reach the end, but if i check the solution the file that was supposed to be generated is missing.

I'm new to this kind of things so it's probably a dumb question, but can someone help me?

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, click 'Show All Files' at the top corner of Solution Explorer.

Comment: Did you check the bin directory? anyway dont use relative paths

Comment: I checked the bin and it was there, I was looking in another "assets" folder.
But, the file appears empty when I open it and I can only open it while the code is not running, otherwise it will crash telling me that the file is opened in another process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You are closing filestream before you write anything
2- You are trying to write a array . But you send just array object to the file you need the loop for that

```
   public static class GenerateText
    {
        static string obstacle = "0";
        static string node = "1";



        public static void CreateMap(int x, int y, string name)
        {
            string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/" + name + ".txt";
            if (!File.Exists(name + ".txt"))//if there is a empty file with this name
            {                               //function doesnt work make sure you 
                                            //delete any empty file 
                FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);

                string[,] map = new string[x, y];
                for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
                {
                    for (int h = 0; h < y; ++h)
                    {
                        int randomValue = RandomGenerator.GetRandom(0, 10);
                        if (randomValue > 6 || i == 0 || h == 0 || i == x || h == y)
                        {
                            map[i, h] = obstacle;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            map[i, h] = node;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int a = 0; a < x; a++)
                {
                    for (int b = 0; b < y; b++)
                    {
                        writer.Write(map[a, b]);
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }
                writer.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I just change your directory before u try just fix that

Comment: you're right, adding the writing loop and changing the Close() procedure solved, now the file is created and written

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your filestream before you write to your StreamWriter!

```
fs.Close();
writer.WriteLine(map);
```

It is better to have Using statements for such cases, then you minimise such problems.  With or without brackets is your choice.

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))

string[,] map = new string[x, y];
for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
{
    for (int h = 0; h < y; ++h)
    {
        int randomValue = RandomGenerator.GetRandom(0, 10);
        if (randomValue > 6 || i == 0 || h == 0 || i == x || h == y)
        {
            map[i, h] = obstacle;
        }
        else
        {
            map[i, h] = node;
        }
    }
}
writer.WriteLine(map);
```